# Rigging a stickman figure

Tags: rigging

I'm trying to rig this model, but I'm getting a lot of errors. I'm new to Blender and trying to learn how to use this model. Any help would be appreciated.[image: My Rig trial]
[image: The model I need rigged].

[image]

Comment: What difficuly have you met? Parenting With Automatic Weights should work fine

Comment: I tried but some faces are being dragged when I try to move, Eg when I move the head only some faces move although I have selected all of them and assigned to the head

Comment: maybe share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: i just shared @moonboots

Comment: You have overlapping vertices, also you should simplify your topology as I showed you, parent the forearm bone to the upperarm, align their rotation to the axis (Shift N)

Comment: I don't know how to do that but I will research on that... Thank you @moonboots